# Decoding utf-8 in python

Tags: python, utf-8

I have an expression like this that produces the list of bytes of the utf-8 representation.

```
list(chr(number).encode("utf-8"))
```

But how to do this in reverse?

Say, I have 2 bytes [292, 200] as a list, how can I decode them into a symbol?

Comment: Hello, can you provide one example of a `number` ?

Comment: b.decode('utf-8','replace')

Comment: print (list(chr(200).encode("utf-8"))) gives [195, 136]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to remember that char only stores 8 bits: -128 to 127. So if 'number' is bigger than char limits it won't work.

   ```
   number = 127
   print(f"number: {number}")
   li = list(chr(number).encode("utf-8"))
   print(f"List of byte: {li}")
   dec = int.from_bytes(li, byteorder='big')
   print(f"Type dec: {type(dec)}")
   print(f"Value dec: {dec}")
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   number = 128
   print(f"number: {number}")
   li = list(chr(number).encode("utf-8"))
   print(f"List of byte: {li}")
   dec = int.from_bytes(li, byteorder='big')
   print(f"Type dec: {type(dec)}")
   print(f"Value dec: {dec}")
   ```

   [image]

   Take a look at [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) for converting values

Answer (score 2):

You can call `bytes` on a list of integers in the range 0..255.

So your example reverses like this:

```
>>> bytes([195, 136]).decode('utf8')
'È'
```

If you want the codepoint, wrap it in `ord()`:

```
>>> ord(bytes([195, 136]).decode('utf8'))
200
```

Note: the last step only works if the byte sequence corresponds to a single Unicode character (codepoint).